# How to get IEX cloud API Key and make it available to my python code?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, dataset, data-science

```
# Import DataReader
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader

# Import date
from datetime import date

# Set start and end dates
start = date(2016,1,1)
end = date(2016,12,31)

# Set the ticker
ticker = "AAPL"

# Set the data source
data_source = "iex"

# Import the stock prices
stock_prices = DataReader(ticker, data_source, start, end)

# Display and inspect the result
print(stock_prices.head())
stock_prices.info()
```

I can import DataReader and use 'iex' in a virtual environment easily but when I'm trying to do the same in my python interpreter I got a ValueError Exception also it asks for the IEX cloud API key. I haven't heard the term before even from my instructor. Please explain me what it is, also how to implement so that I can get rid of this error.

[Error I have got!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhkmH.png)

Comment: Do you have an IEX Cloud APIkey set up under a virtual environment?

Comment: In the virtual environment, they never use the term IEX Key, also I didn't have any problem in executing the above code but when I copy-paste the same code in my interpreter it is the console that says "API cloud Key must be provided", you can see the same in the above screenshot that I have attached

Comment: Since APIkey is required for normal data acquisition, we need to look into the virtual environment.